# DynamoDB SDK for PHP: Is it possible to scan a list of items with key of a nested item?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a structure like that:

```
{
    Id: "55e0173c485dd",
    Revisions: [
        {
            CAS: "2132-123-123",
            ComponentName: "bar"
        },
        {
            ComponentName: "baz"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to perform scan by "ComponentName" of item in the list?
I found the only way to scan with params like that:

```
[

    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
        ':component' => [
            'M' => [
                'ComponentName' => ['S' => 'bar']
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'FilterExpression' => 'contains (Revisions, :component)'
];
```

But it checks the full item match and not able to find item with "CAS" field in my case.

I need something like "$elemMatch" in MongoDB:

**http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't currently support querying/filtering on an attribute within a Map within a List. You can as you said, specify the entire Map and use the expression "contains(path.to.list, :map)" and specify the full map in the expression attribute values.

That being said, if you're paying to read back all items with a scan anyway, you could just retrieve the items and process them on the client side to evaluate your condition.

Comment: Yep, now I see. Thanks a lot!